# Python: pertaining to "division impossible" error

Tags: python

decimal.InvalidOperation: []

The error above came up on line 15 of the following code (its the line with the while statement):

```
from decimal import *    
accuracy = 60    
getcontext().prec = accuracy


def function():
    for element in range(1, 50):
        var_a = Decimal(1) / Decimal(element)
        count = 1
        if round(var_a, accuracy - 10) == var_a:
            print((element, 0))
            continue
        while (var_a * (10**count)) - ((var_a * (10**count)) % 1) != int:
            count += 1
        print((element, count))

function()
```

I am trying to write code to find out how long a recurring cycle is for a given range of fractions (for example, 1 / 6 is 0.16666, and has a 1 digit recurring cycle, while 1 / 11 is 0.090909090909... and has a 2 digit recurring cycle).

I don't really know what the error means or what I can do about it.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: for BrenBarn,

File "C:/Users/Louie McConnell/PycharmProjects/Prime Stuff/reciprocal cycles.py", line 15, in function

```
while (var_a * (10**count)) - ((var_a * (10**count)) % 1) != int:
```

decimal.InvalidOperation: [ class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible']

Comment: Please paste the complete error message.

Comment: You can't compare numbers to `int` - it is an inbuilt function. Even if it runs you won't get the results you expect. You need to use another method to check if a number is an integer.

Comment: Why are you doing `% 1`? What do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def is_integral(d): 
    return d.to_integral() == d
```

in

```
while not is_integral(var_a * (10**count)) - ((var_a * (10**count)) % 1):
```